# typeerror: Property value expected type of string but got null

Tags: typescript, react-native

anyone got any solution: I am getting error like this too but for react-native components like ActivityIndicator, Button, KeyboardAvoidingView

for example this kind of error: typeerror: node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/ActivityIndicator/ActivityIndicator.js: Property value expected type of string but got null

And the interesting thing is this error is occurring on iOS only, Android works just fine. Anyone got any idea ?

I tried doing all the things, yarn reset cache and re-installing all the node_modules but nothing works.

Comment: did you figured out what was this?

Comment: Nope, could not fix it. Please let me know if you find any solution for this.